# AWS Lightsail instance overcoming system hang

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail, fault-tolerance

Suppose, I have a lightsail instance running some java backend. For whatever reason, this instance could potentially hang/freeze and basically require a reboot.

What is the standard/recommended way of dealing with such cases ?

Basically, client app1 makes api calls to the backend. I would like the api call to be successful even if the primary backend fails, through a replicated backend instance.

Is there anything out of the box that I can use with my instances that aws provides or do I need to run two backend instances and handle failures on the client side ?

Comment: You are probably getting beyond what lightsail provides. A standard setup on AWS for this is multiple EC2 instances behind an AWS load balancer.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm. One thing I would like to clarify, with the load-balancer, the client applications are unaware of the multiple instances and will make calls to the same endpoint regardless of any failures

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.